# GUIのない​プログラミング

Tags: c++, gui

どのようにGUIなしでプログラムすることが可能です。私はBell LabsでBjourneプログラミングのイメージをキーボードだけで見てきました。あなたの前でそれを見ることなく、あなたがしていることをどのように知ることができますか？

English version: I am trying to understand how programmers know what they are doing without looking at the GUI. How do you know what code is in which file and what file is in which folder?

Comment: こちらのご質問ですが、私には質問者さんの疑問点がよく分かりませんでした。英文を併記して頂いても構いませんので、ご質問の意図をもう少し教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 私はプログラマーがGUIを見ずに何をしているのかを知る方法を理解しようとしています。どのようなコードがどのファイルにあり、どのファイルがどのフォルダにあるのか、どのように知っていますか？

Comment: English version: I am trying to understand how programmers know what they are doing without looking at the GUI. How do you know what code is in which file and what file is in which folder?

Comment: 日本語の文章と、English versionの文章の内容が一致していません。　何が知りたいのでしょうか？？？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI なしでプログラミングする場合、command-line interface (CLI) 経由でプログラミングする場合が多いでしょう。

現代的なパソコンでは、[ターミナル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB)または[ターミナルエミュレータ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF)が提供する CLI を使って操作します。具体的には、Windows であれば cmd.exe や PowerShell など、Mac や Linux / Unix では bash などが有名です。

[image: ターミナルのイメージ画像です]

操作する上でファイルの一覧を見たりファイルの中身を閲覧したりするには、種々のコマンドを使います。

例1: ファイルの一覧を見るには Windows では `dir` コマンド、Unix 系では `ls` コマンドを使います。

例2: プログラムが書かれたテキストファイルの中身を閲覧するには、Windows では `type` コマンド、Unix 系では `cat` コマンド、`more` コマンド、`less` コマンドなどを使います。また、CLI 上で動作するエディタを使って表示することも多いです。

[image: コマンドライン操作例のgifアニメーションです]

※ 他にも歴史的にはディスプレイ無しにパンチカードとプリンタで入出力するインターフェースなどありますが、この回答では触れるだけに留めておきます。

Comment: この回答は、最後のセクションで特に意味があります。私はBell LabsのBjarneの写真を見ていて、キーボードだけで何のCLIやGUIも使っていないことをどうやって知っているのか不思議でした。

Comment: @Cody Rutscher CLI も使わないのですか？

Comment: 私はあなたが意味することを理解していない